# error reading .xls file by exceljs node module

Tags: javascript, excel, readfile, xls, exceljs

Package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs

Version:

```
"exceljs": "^0.2.31",
```

Getting this error:
[Error: invalid signature: 0xe011cfd0]

when reading (dot xls) file.

> .xls

```
workbook.xlsx.readFile(inputFile.file)
```

Getting the error in the .catch(err){}

I am looking for a generic code that can read both .xls and .xls**x** formats.

I will be grateful for any of your inputs on this.

Answer (score 0):

In case somebody is looking for this, they solved it in 0.2.6 version:

https://github.com/exceljs/exceljs/issues/28

Regards